# How can I find out all audio files whose formats are supported by AVAudioPlayer in Lion 10.7?

Tags: cocoa, metadata, spotlight

I want to use codes like this.

```
NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
[query setSearchScopes: [NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/Someone/Music" isDirectory:YES]]];
[query setPredicate: predicate];
...
...
```

Now how do I suppose to set "predicate" to ***filter out those files with unsupported format??***

```
kMDItemCodezs,kMDItemMediaTypes,kMDItemContentType,kMDItemKind?
```

Which one should I use? And what are all the possible values of these attibutes corresponding to the supported format in AVAudioPlayer in Lion 10.7? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To obtain a list of most supported formats, you can use `AudioFileGetGlobalInfo` in the `AudioToolbox` framework to get the UTIs supported by Core Audio (using `kAudioFileGlobalInfo_AllUTIs`):

```
UInt32 size;
NSArray *all;
OSStatus err;

err = AudioFileGetGlobalInfoSize(kAudioFileGlobalInfo_AllUTIs, 0, NULL, &size);
if (err == noErr)
    err = AudioFileGetGlobalInfo(kAudioFileGlobalInfo_AllUTIs, 0, NULL, &size, &all);
if (err == noErr)
    NSLog(@"UTIs: %@", all);
[all release];
```

On 10.7, this gives me:

```
"public.aiff-audio",
"public.ulaw-audio",
"org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio",
"com.microsoft.waveform-audio",
"public.3gpp2",
"com.apple.coreaudio-format",
"public.3gpp",
"public.mp3",
"public.au-audio",
"public.mpeg-4-audio",
"public.mpeg-4",
"com.apple.m4a-audio",
"public.aifc-audio"
```

Unfortunately UTIs aren't defined for some of the more obscure data formats (e.g. `.mp1`/`.mp2`) Core Audio supports; if you're happy with the above subset, then just use the UTIs.

Then turn those into a `NSMetadataQuery` (`kMDItemContentType` for `kAudioFileGlobalInfo_AllUTIs`).  If you want to cover the rest of the formats, you can match by HFS type and extension: `kMDItemFSTypeCode` for `kAudioFileGlobalInfo_AllHFSTypeCodes`, and a wildcard match of `kMDItemFSName` for `kAudioFileGlobalInfo_AllExtensions`.  You can use `afconvert -hf` to display both of these.

Matching with `NSMetadataQuery` will of course not look inside all of the files, so it'll still find text files renamed with a `.mp3` extension. Since Spotlight does try to index other audio attributes, you could try checking `kMDItemAudioBitRate` and so forth; these will be missing on a file that isn't actually an audio file.  Depending on how accurate you want to be in filtering, you can also try opening each file to see if it's playable.

Comment: I found all the supported Format IDs in `CoreAudioTypes.h`,can I turn those into a `NSMetadataQuery`? If it can,how? Thanks, Nicholas Riley.

Comment: It's a much better idea for you to use an API since the supported formats may change in future (for better or worse). You will need to construct a query that checks for any of the UTIs, or type codes or extensions, as I described above.

Answer (score 1):

Use `kMDItemContentTypeTree`, and [the audio type](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kUTTypeAudio). This will match any audio files, ignoring movie files. If you want to include movie files, search for [the audio-visual content type](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kUTTypeAudiovisualContent), which the audio type conforms to (descends from).

Edit: This will match *all* known audio types, regardless of whether Core Audio (let alone AVAudioPlayer) can play them. Nicholas Riley's solution is better.

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"public.audio in %@", kMDItemContentTypeTree];
Can this filter out those files with unsupported format?

Comment: No, because you're passing a name, not a collection, so `IN` won't work. From the Predicate Programming Guide: “Spotlight requires comparison clauses to take the form "`KEY operator VALUE`" and does not accept "`VALUE operator KEY`".” The correct format string is simply `kMDItemContentTypeTree == %@` (with `kUTTypeAudio` passed as the argument). I know `==` looks odd with an array-valued key on the left and a string on the right, but the Metadata framework does do the right thing.