# Determine whether mp4 is a audio or video in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Since mp4 is a container file format it can store audio as well as video files. What i am struggling to find out is its true media type. (Whether its a audio or video) Could this be done in IOS (objective c) ?

Comment: Perhaps this library could help you -> https://github.com/aidansteele/MagicKit

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136153/how-can-i-find-out-all-audio-files-whose-formats-are-supported-by-avaudioplayer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:<URL to mp4>];
BOOL hasVideo = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].count > 0;
BOOL hasAudio = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio].count > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    BOOL isMP4VideoType; //Global Variables;
    BOOL isMP4AudioType; //Global Variables;

    //Create an object of AVAsset  class With MP4 URL.
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:YOUR_MP4_URL];

    NSArray *aryVideoTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSArray *aryAudioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    if([aryVideoTracks count]!=0)
    {
     isMP4VideoType = YES;
    }else if([aryVideoTracks count]!=0)
    {
     isMP4AudioType = YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AVURLAsset* asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:_assetUrl options:nil];
NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
AVAssetTrack * audioTrack = [audioTracks firstObject];
```

> ```
> if([track hasMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaCharacteristicAudible]){
>
> }
> ```